# yii2 после генирации gii crud нет доступа к сгенерированному коду?

Tags: php, yii2, gii

yii2 после генирации  gii crud нет доступа  к сгенерированному коду.

Создание CRUD:

```
"Model Class": app\models\Comment
"Controller Class": app\controllers\CommentController
```

перехожу на адрес

```
http://myblog.loc/comment
```

и браузер показывает "`Not Found`"

(ubuntu, apache2, права на все папки в `myblog.loc` - 777)
пример отсюда: http://rgblog.ru/page/sozdanie-sajta-na-yii-framework-20-chast-2

В чем может быть причина, почему оно не работает?

Comment: Может где-то роут переопределяется?

Comment: в дереве проекта есть такой каталог, с файлом views\comment\index.php?
Опишите подробнее, какие действия Вы делали, а также подробное описание ошибки, если таковое имеется

Comment: А как у вас настроен url manager ? Возможно дело в этом.
Попробуйте открыть по ссылке `http://myblog.loc/index.php?r=comment`